# Anyone using an Alpha Litebook? Have you upgraded to Juno?

Tags: updates

The Alpha Litebook, a short lived (but wonderful) Linux laptop came with what is claimed to be ElementaryOS but said it was based on Ubuntu 16.04. The company is now gone as are all pages of support about it. Few apparently got their machine before the company went defunct. My machine runs fine and I still love it but I wonder about upgrading the OS. Anyone have a Litebook and if so, has anyone put a newer version of ElementryOS on it? For info on the now-defunct Litebook, check https://itsfoss.com/elementary-litebook/